# C programming switch statements to find a number or a letter

Tags: c, signals, postfix-notation

Hello everyone I was trying the questions from the C programming language book by by Brian W. Kernighan  (Author), Dennis M. Ritchie (Author).The book provides the code for a basic reverse Polish Calculator but I do not understand how `#define NUMBER '0'` works with the switch statement:

How is it able to capture all the numbers although we did not have case for each number. Also the next questions asks me to handle cases like `sin`, `cos` or `pow`. I am assuming there is also a similar way to do it but if explained would help me better.

The `getop` gets next operator or numeric operand, `push` and `pop` are regular stack functions and `atof` converts ascii to floats.

```
#define NUMBER '0'


    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[100];

    while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF) {
        switch (type) {
            case NUMBER:
                push(atof(s));
                break;
            case '+':
                push(pop() + pop());
                break;
            case '*':
                push(pop() * pop());
                break;
            case '-':
                op2 = pop();
                push(pop() - op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0)
                    push(pop() / op2);
                else
                    printf("error: zero divisor\n");
                break;
            case '%':
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0)
                    push((int)pop() % (int)op2);
                else
                    printf("error: division by zero\n");
                break;
            case '\n':
                printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
                break;
            default:
                printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that `getop()` returns `NUMBER` if its argument `s` happens to be numeric.

Comment: Look at the line `switch(type)` until enlightenment comes.

Comment: @Hasturkun yeah I saw what happened thanks.

Comment: @n.m. lol just got enlighten

Comment: What is `getop` ? And please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @MichaelWalz sorry and okay I will. getop is just a function that gets the next operator or numeric operand. So in the case of handling sin, cos or pow I just need to make sure it returns a different constant expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C preprocessor performs textual replacement before the compiler reads and parses your source code.  `NUMBER` is replaced with `'0'` which is the value of the character representing the digit `0`.

The function `getop()` probably returns the value `'0'` when a number is parsed from the input and copies the digits to `s`. `atof()` converts that to a number.

If you have access to the source code for `getop()`, you will see how it parses numbers, white space, comments and operators.

Note that you should not use `%` with floating point values. You should use `fmod()` instead.

Comment: Integer division overflow should not be an issue as using floating point arithmetic...

Comment: @Aconcagua: OK, missed that.  Why bother testing zero division then? Dividing a non zero value by zero produces an infinity and 0.0/0.0 produces a NaN.

Comment: Mathematical correctness probably - however, I missed that for %, indeed a conversion to int is done...

Comment: @chqrlie thanks for editing the question and answering it as well. I am very new to stack exchange and it really feels good to know that this community is out there. I know everyone gets reputation points for these activities but feels like thats just a form of encouragement. Thank you all